# ¿"Listar", como verbo, choca?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario

En inglés se usa seguido *list* como verbo.  Hoy por primera vez ví lo equivalente en español:

> Voy a ver si encuentro un ejemplo como los que listé en la pregunta.

¿Choca *listar* usado así?  Es decir, ¿se oye como anglicismo forzado?  ¿O ya se acepta en el uso cotidiano?

Comment: Uuf... para mí mucho.  *listar* es forma alternativa de *alistar* que quiere decir *to enlist* (en sentido darte de alta en el servicio militar).  Menos me chocaría *listear*, que emplea el sufijo *-ear* a base de *lista*, no obstante, viendo en Internet, *listar* ya tiene algún uso.  *apunté / incluí / puse / enumeré / etc.* mejor, diría yo.

Comment: Gracias, @guifa, me molestaba también, pero no sabía se era algo nuevo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personalmente, no me choca, pero sin duda se debe a que en mi ámbito profesional (informática), usamos muchísimos extranjerismos, y traducciones más o menos literales del inglés, en detrimento del término correcto español.

Así que si estás en un contexto informático, úsalo sin miedo. En otro contexto, quizás sería oportuno buscar una alternativa.

Answer (score 8):

Sí. Choca un poco. Creo que en español favoreceríamos [enumerar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Fqp5Qgd) con ese significado, mucho antes que *listar*.

> [Enumerar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Fqp5Qgd)
>
> 1. tr. Enunciar sucesiva y ordenadamente las partes de un conjunto.

Aplicado al ejemplo:

> Voy a ver si encuentro un ejemplo como los que **enumeré** en la pregunta.

Otros sinónimos podrían ser

- inventariar,
- catalogar,
- detallar

e incluso "registrar", pero para mi gusto `enumerar` es el que mejor se adapta al significado de `to list`.

Answer (score 5):

El diccionario de la lengua lo recoge:

[**Listar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NQK3Wrk)

> 1. tr. alistar (‖ inscribir en lista).

[**Alistar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1tbcVsk)

> 1. tr. Sentar o inscribir en lista a alguien. U. t. c. prnl.

Por lo que parece que es un uso aceptado.

En la práctica, nunca lo he oido utilizar (ni *alistar* con esa acepción), y "me suena raro" pero creo que se entiende perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

Disculpa, pero listar sí choca, pero "enlistar" se usa mucho.

[Enlistar DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=enlistar):

> enlistar.
>   1. tr. Méx. alistar (‖ inscribir en lista).
>   2. tr. Méx. y R. Dom. reclutar (‖ alistar reclutas).

Comment: Úsase *enlistar*, por lo menos según el enlace que tienes en la respuesta, para fines militares. Puede que tenga usos más generalizados pero la fuente no los indica